# How to add [ngClass] to dynamically created element in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an Nokia map addon, which needs me to create markers on the map by using document.createElement('div').
I want to bind this new div to ngClass, is there possibility of doing this in Angular?

if you know the terminology of what I am trying to explain over-here, that would be a great help, since I did this kind of stuff on Vue and React without problem, I just can't explain to google(or anyone for that matter) what is it that I want to do.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code.

Comment: I made a workaround which worked(JS style),
but it's not good to do it in Angular.
I don't think anybody would care to see a simple code of adding a class depending on a simple condition.

Comment: Instead of using `createElement` can you use an angular template with `*ngFor` ?

Comment: Not the solution, I just generate them, the map adds them to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your can achieve this in the following way

let's say you've created a `div` like

```
var div = '<div ng-class="yourClassName">Any text here or whatever</div>';
```

Now you'll have to make dynamic compilation for this element to bind it with `controller scope` like

```
  var newDiv= $compile(div)($scope);
```

Now you can append them with any `DOM` element. For example

```
$('.anyOtherDivClass').append(newDiv)
```

This will allow all of the events like `ng-click` etc to trigger for your dynamically created elements.

Ps. Don't forget to inject `$compile` service in your controller.

Hope this helps

Comment: I meant angular 2

Answer (score 0):

Use @HostBinding with a getter function to return whether a class should exist or not.

Something like:

```
@HostBinding("class.newclass") get isInfo() { return this.type === "info" }
```